# Adding empty space between items of RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to add empty spaces between items of a RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager but I can't find anything which solves my problem.
I am creating a custom calendar and I have to make a custom grid from scratch. The first day of the month should be placed farther from the start when it is not the first day of the week.

I have achieved a similar result by passing a `firstItemLocation` to my RecyclerView adapter and overriding the `onBindViewHolder` method like this:

```java
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position < firstItemLocation) {
            holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.tv.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%d", list.get(position - firstItemLocation)));
        }
    }
```

It works fine but in a hypothetical situation when the user has to scroll it adds random empty spaces and glitches like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca3f3.png).

Any seggestions to make it better without that glitch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read about "recycling pattern", how it works and why - `RecyclerView` got its name because of this, so its very important to understand how this works

but in short:

inside `onBindViewHolder` you have to call desired methods ALWAYS. you are calling `setVisibility` only inside `if` and not in `else`. try with bellow snippet

```
    if (position < firstItemLocation) {
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tv.setText("")
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tv.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%d", list.get(position - firstItemLocation)));
    }
```

thats because `holder` may be a "recycled" instance, used previously to draw another list item, and its set up is still applied to views